# How it can be a race condition. Or it is something wrong with my code

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I think I am facing problem of race condition, but not sure.
Following is my code.

```
while(1) 
{
    int newsocket_fd; = accept(socket_fd,(struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &client_len);

    if (newsocket_fd < 0) 
    {
          perror("Error on accept");
    }
    else
    {
        pthread_create( &threadNewClient, NULL, NewClient, (void *)&newsocket_fd);
    }
}
```

I am sending address of int variable (newsocket_fd) as thread argument.

```
void* NewClient(void * thread_args)
{
    int client_socket = *(int*)thread_args;
    char buffer[256];   
    int n;
    stringstream userInput,responseString; 

    printf(KBLU "Client conneted  %d\n",client_socket);
}
```

Here I am receiving thread argument and typecast it. When I print (or use) its value, it most of the time gives value which are sent to previous threads (same thread function). I searched on net, and someone suggests it is because of race condition.

When I send value instead of address as argument, it works fine. I am accessing same address having different values, how come it could be race condition.

Thanks in advance.

@Edit: created int newsocket_fd; inside while loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're sending the address of a stack-located integer (`newsocket_fd`). This will get reused then next time a socket is accepted. What's wrong with just sending the integer value?

Comment: Please look at my edited post now. Here I am recreating int newsocket_fd, still it is race condition?

Comment: What's wrong with just sending the integer value? Ans. Now I am sending only int value. Technically correct. But conceptually it is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: If you do it that way then as soon as you loop, the `newsocket_fd` will go out of scope and so will no longer have a valid address. If your thread starts fast enough then it'll be fine otherwise you'll be accessing an invalid pointer. (In reality the compiler will probably do the same thing in both cases)

Comment: After the edit, the code still has the same problem. You send the address of a variable that you overwrite with the next `accept`. It doesn't go out of scope now, but still its value is not meaningful. Send the integer value, not a pointer to it. Or better yet, don't spawn one thread per connection in the first place, which is an ill-advised design that doesn't scale well.

Comment: @Damon: one thread per connection in the first place, which is an ill-advised design --> can you please suggest, why it is bad, and what to do instead.

Comment: If you're writing this in `C++` and have access to the `Boost` libraries then I would highly recommend using `Boost.Asio` or even just the non-boost `Asio` library from http://think-async.com. There is a bit of a learning curve but the benefits are vast in my opinion.

Comment: @Nick: Thanks. Not sure about current project. But sure I will learn Boost.Asio. From long time I am waiting to learn boost. (Lazy me.)

Comment: @Damon Actually, for anything but trivial protocols, one thread per connection, or even two threads per connection, is the preferred solution.

Comment: @user2481987 Rather than Boost.Asio, I'd recommend Boost.Threads.  Doing the IO asynchronously doesn't really solve the problem; threads are a lot cleaner.  In this case, of course, casting the `int` to a `void*`, and recasting the `void*` back to a `int` in the new thread, is the simplest solution.

Comment: Boost threads or C++11 threads, whichever you've got.  For the pthreads version: you need to change to `pthread_create(..., (void*)newsocket_fd)` and in `NewClient()`, `int client_socket = static_cast<int>(thread_args)`.  Forget `asio` until your server needs to be able to handle more than 30 or 60 simultaneously open connections.

Comment: @JamesKanze: @user2481987: One _process_ per connection was the preferred solution until about the mid-1990s, when _the internet_ meant a few thousand machines and 5 simultaneous users were the equivalent of a _very busy site_. One _thread_ per connection is an attempt to make the whole concept somewhat more lightweight (context switches and memory), but it is not _that much_ different, and comes with additional disadvantages as compared to processes. The _preferrable_ solution has been, for years, to multiplex I/O using a single thread (e.g. `select` or `poll`).

Comment: Also, contrary to common belief, spawning threads is not a cheap operation, not under any other OS, and not under Linux either. In fact, spawning threads is (other than the common belief) quite expensive under Linux as the OS has no notion of "thread" at all. Calling `sys_clone` (which is what you _effectively_ do) every time `accept` returns is not something one would really want to do.

Comment: Not only does `Asio` allow for overlapped/multiplexed IO but it can be an excellent foundation on which to build an event-driven asynchronous architecture regardless of whether you're doing networking or not.

Comment: @Damon You've got it backwards.  Asynchronous IO was the solution back in the 70's, when connections only did very simple things.  Today, in most cases, it's much simpler to use threads (or even processes, if you can).

Comment: @Nick Certainly, but most protocols today are complicated enough that you don't want them to be event driven.

Comment: @JamesKanze: You're of course joking, right? Multiplexing and non-blocking I/O nowadays handles 10-20k concurrent users without any trouble on a rather low-end machine and is practically limited only by what physically fits onto the ethernet cable (or by how many interrupts per second the kernel can handle, or by disk/memory bandwidth, etc.). Forking servers start to have very noticeable context switch and virtual memory effects with a few hundred concurrent users (or with a few _dozen_ on data that is modified!) and regularly bail out on a few thousand, even on a high-end machine.

Comment: While threading is not _great_ for scalability, forking is really only acceptable for its advantages of perfect isolation and simplicity of design if data is strictly static, concurrency is low to moderate at best, and if connections are entirely independent. In all other cases, it will be a performance and maintenance nightmare. For example, if one of your forked processes modifies a memory page, the next one accessing it will fault. If a hundred processes do that a few times per second, your server will be 100% loaded doing nothing but copying memory pages.

Comment: I'm assuming you're all familiar with the C10k problem: http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html

Comment: @Damon And how many applications have to handle 10-20k concurrent users on a rather low-end machine?  In almost all cases, if that's the problem, the cheapest solution is to upgrade the machine.  And keep the code easily maintainable.

Comment: "640K of memory should be enough for anybody"... ;-)

Comment: @Damon FWIW: the limiting factor for the servers I've worked on
has usually been disk throughput, not threading.  If you need
transaction integrity, you block the disk for at least 10ms per
transaction.  The cost of creating a new thread is negligible 
compared to that.  And of course, if you can use processes
instead of threads, you can spawn the work off to other
machines, and get some true parallelism.

Comment: @JamesKanze: This depends. For many servers, disk troughput is not a limiting factor since data can be pulled from the buffer cache. For other server types, disk may of course be the limiting factor. Most modern high-performance web servers (as one example of "server") use a single-thread approach. As for what forking can easily do, you should consider that for example the redis authors recommend background saving no more often than once every few minutes. Why? Because bg save forks, and fork (indirectly, via the faults it generates) very noticeably impacts the main process' performance.

Comment: @Damon I'll buy the argument about cache misses, partially at least.  (If each connection is accessing different data, you'll get the cache misses anyway.)  Maybe our difference of opinion is because we've worked on different types of servers.  My servers have always had client modifiable state, which had to be persistent, with transactional integrity.  So you cannot respond to the actual request until the modified data is physically on the disk (files opened with `O_SYNC` and `O_DSYNC`).  The requests also frequently involve significant CPU.  If you're just serving up web pages, it's diff.

Answer (score 3):

`newsocket_fd` may be modified (or worse, destroyed and re-created) before the new thread reads it from the pointer you gave it. This is definitely a race condition.

The easiest fix is simply not sharing the same variable between threads. If you absolutely must do it for some reason or other, then you must ensure it won't be modified before the thread is done reading it, using some synchronization object (condition).

Comment: Please look at my edited post now. Here I am recreating int newsocket_fd, still it is race condition?

Comment: Yes, only an even worse one now because the thread may access a stack variable why it no longer exists. I edited my post too.

Comment: Only one answer can be marked as accepted. Otherwise this is also satisfied my requirement.